# Need free javascript library for Single Page Web Application

Tags: javascript

We are developing a web page where the table will populate with asychronous ajax calls every defined interval. The user selects few rows and sends it back to server.
I tried knockout. Its a great library but right now I am having problem of memory leak and unable to detect the cause. The web page is supposed to run for hours hence memory management is essential.

Any other suggestions ?

**Update**
Here is the question I posted on knockout forum. 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/knockoutjs/Jis8AgHhPRc

Basically I am having problem every time I bind the "new" data to existing viewModel. I haven't shown the checkboxes select functionality  as I haven't been able to resolve the memory issue yet for the new updates.

Comment: How are you calling on a defined interval?  What do you mean the user selects few rows and sends back?  You tried knockout for what exactly?  How do you know you have memory leaks?  What browser are you using?  Posting some code and details on the steps you have taken would be the best start.  Just edit your question and add details.

Comment: Updated with a link to the problem description and possible approach for knockout js.